# Saitek x45 HOTAS range values not mapping properly

Tags: controllers, hardware

I have a saitek x45 HOTAS. I have the drivers downloaded from saiteks ftp server [here](ftp://ftp.saitek.com/pub/software/x45/). I've done the built in windows joystick calibration wizard, and shows as operating perfectly fine with a normal range of motion.

How ever in game (elite dangerous) and on [html5 Gamepad Tester](http://html5gamepad.com/), the values my stick is outputting seem to be off. my joystick's entire range of motion becomes confined to the Upper right quadrant of its range of motion. On the Gamepad tester, every value outputted by the stick is in the -9,-9 range. And the midpoint on my throttle and dials are all way off.

I thought windows calibration was supposed to account for this, but neither seems to agree. Any ideas on what I can do to restore full range of motion and functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Went into regedit and searched for saitek and deleted anything that came up. maybe reckless but effective. Also went to Sys32 and deleted all dlls that started with the string "saic". after this was done, i uninstalled the controller, unplugged it, and plugged it back in. windows went into some autoinstaller and pulled drivers from the web. when it was complete, it registered my hats as a bunch of buttons instead of hats but they still work perfectly. analog range of motion was restored and a quick calibration got everything working.